# "Close All But This" in Windows 7 Taskbar

Tags: windows-7

Is there some sort of app/hack for Windows 7 that allows you to have the same functionality as "Close All But This" on a Visual Studio tab (where it closes all other tabs but that one)?  I'd like to be able to close all grouped windows but the one I'm clicking on (think Outlook - keep main window open but close all message windows).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to close an open windows quickly using Aero Peak (hover over the application icon to get the preview of all open windows).

- Either click on the red 'x'
- Middle-Click on each preview

Otherwise there isn't any direct way to close all but active windows that I know of, but there could be a 3rd-Party app that would put a "Close all but this" in the jump list.

Comment: I didn't know about the middle click - that'd help for most situations. 30+ Windows, it gets old fast though. Might have to write my own.

Comment: I agree, it'd be a great feature, maybe I'll look at writing a PowerToys for Win7 as well.